# QGIS SVG-Fill pdf-output converted to EMF via Inkscape black borders

Tags: qgis, emf

I imported a "wave" SVG fill for lakes. Exporting a PDF is nice. But when I convert the PDF to EMF (for Word import) with Inkscape the lakes have a black background around:

[image: black background]

How can I get rid of this?